# Cost efficient way of displaying web page view count with Go/Datastore

Tags: go, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I'd like for each page to display the number of visitors; using Google Analytics does not seem to be an option since too many visitors use adblockers.

I guess there is no smart way to do it with Go since I doubt there is an efficient way of storing the counter in a text file; whereas using Datastore seems like a good option, but I guess the costs of updating and retrieving the view count on every request is not worth it.

I was hoping someone might be able to recommend a good and cheap solution (that preferably does not rely on third-party services that are not a part of the Google Cloud Platform)

Comment: You could count in your application, and push the count to datastore every N minutes or something.

Comment: Hmm, that's a great idea, and in case there are several thousands of even millions of pages then I guess can just add the visited pages to a list and remove them if they haven't been visited for X amount of time

Comment: This is one of those where you have to ask yourself how accurate you need it to be. If you are ok with occasionally having some counting lost (server dies / whatever), then @captncraig 's solution is exactly what you want. If you need super accuracy, you need an atomic counter, but you'll pay for it in complexity.